# Why cannot run bower update command in Package Manager Console

Tags: jquery, bower, package-manager-console

Its an existing project and I want to upgrade jquery version in it. For that on package console manager(PMC) I ran **bower update jquery --force-latest** and even **bower update jquery** but to no avail. It's giving error as shown in screenshot.

[image]

My bower.json file is in the project which I have located in PMC's Default Project as shown in figure:

[image]

I later changed the version of jquery in .json file from **"jquery": "2.1.3"** to **"jquery": "3.3.1"** . Still no luck! I'm new to this and don't now what am I missing?

Here's my bower.json file;

{
  "name": "XXXXXXX.Web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.15",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "jquery-ui": "1.12.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.15",
    "lodash": "3.7.0",
    "angular-animate": "1.3.9",
    "animate.css": "3.2.0",
    "angular-translate": "2.7.0",
    "amplify": "1.1.2",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.13.0",
    "moment": "momentjs#~2.5.1",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "bootstrap-tagsinput#~0.4.2",
    "autoNumeric": "1.9.30",
    "highcharts": "4.1.5",
    "nouislider": "nouislider#~7.0.6",
    "fullcalendar": "2.3.1",
    "Sortable": "1.2.0",
    "tooltipster": "3.3.0",
    "jszip": "2.4.0",
    "blockui": "blockui#2.70",
    "script.js": "2.5.7",
    "datatables": "1.10.8",
    "jquery.maskedinput": "1.4.1",
    "clockpicker": "0.0.7",
    "mustache.js": "2.1.3",
    "select2": "4.0.3",
    "summernote": "0.6.14",
    "dropzone": "4.0.1",
    "swiper": "2.7.6",
    "keyboard": "1.25.13",
    "history.js": "1.8.0",
    "google-maps": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.3.15"
  }
}

Comment: Have you tried by install latest version of jquery?

Comment: @Hardik But I want to do that though Bower. If you mean manually then this is not what im looking for

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. try to install jquery first using bower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Visual Studio (VS 2013) which contains old GIT version. I updated it with latest and command worked successfully. Don't forget to remove the older version of GIT through Control Panel

Between, I figured out that command could be also be run through ordinary command prompt.

[image]